# When adding scope to the Angular-Seed default View Controllers the test suite now fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-seed

Using a fresh clone of [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) I am attempting some BDD and have added the following tests and code. However, once I add the $scope to the controller, the suite fails on the `expect(view1Ctrl).toBeDefined();` expectation.

Below is the only addition I've made and it causes the noted failure when Karma runs.

**app/view1/view1.js**

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Name";
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your test (view1_test.js) you need to inject $scope into the controller...

```
    describe('myApp.view1 module', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp.view1'));

  describe('view1 controller', function(){

    it('should ....', inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
      //spec body
      var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var view1Ctrl = $controller('View1Ctrl', {$scope: $scope});
      expect(view1Ctrl).toBeDefined();
    }));

  });
});
```